# Exception Flutter from fetch network Image without connection internet

Tags: flutter

after turning off the internet i gets this error: **"Remove network images from cache on any exception during loading"**
my app fetch pictures from api. how can i fix this bug how i prevent that?

```
 return Column(children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                        child: Image.network(thumbnailUrl))])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Cached Network Image Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) if you are developing for android and ios. In Web, the plugin is not working as expected.

Use the following as a widget for your application.

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

Widget commonCacheImageWidget(String? url, {double? width, BoxFit? fit, double? height}) {
  if (url!.startsWith('http')) {
    return CachedNetworkImage(
      placeholder: (context, url) => Image.asset('assets/path....', fit: BoxFit.cover),
      imageUrl: url,
      height: height,
      width: width,
      fit: fit,
    );

  } else {
    return Image.asset(url, height: height, width: width, fit: fit);
  }
}
```

In Placeholder you can have any widget, here am using a local image that is stored as an asset.

Or You can check whether the internet connection is there or not before loading the image and change that to some other widget.